# How to regex a path and all subpathes except one subpath?

Tags: apache-http-server, regex, path

For an webapp I need to AliasMatch a path and all its subpathes in Apache but but I need to exclude subpathpath.

Example:

`AliasMatch /webapp /usr/share/webapp`
Valid pathes would be `/abc.dom/webapp` `/abc.dom/webapp/somepath/do.php`

but I also need to
`AliasMatch /webapp/static /usr/share/webapp/media/static`
Valid pathes would be `/abc.dom/webapp/static/` `/abc.dom/webapp/static/css/`

So I need a regex that matches `/webapp/*` but not `/webapp/static/*` and vice versa.

Any idea? Everything I tried already ended in either the first or the second but not both together.

Comment: your title says "except one subpath", but there is no reference for that exception in the text. Please add some example paths which should be matched, and also what shouldn't, it's very difficult to understand your question now.

Answer (score 2):

```
AliasMatch "^/webapp/((?!static/).*)$" "/usr/share/webapp/$1"
AliasMatch "^/webapp/static/(.*)" "/usr/share/webapp/media/static/$1"
```